# What is the quickest method to find is there intersect between two list?

Tags: c#, list

I have written a code to check intersection between two list.
I need only is there intersection.
Is there a quicker way for it.

```
L,L2 are List<int>

bool working = true;

bool ok=false;
for (int k = 0; k<L.Count && working;k++) {
   if (L2.Any (a => a == L[k])) {
      ok=true;//There is an integer in L and   L2
      working=false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is quickest defined as "quickest to write", like @TimSchmelter 's answer, or is it defined as "quickest to run"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i have overlooked something, but normally you'd use [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0)+`Any`:

```
bool intersects = L.Intersect(L2).Any();
```

This works if the type in the list overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like most .NET classes do. If you use your own you should remember that, otherwise only references are compared.